# Any common attribute between snapshot of Parent(Source) & replica volume in softlayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We are trying to relate common attributes of snapshot created at Parent(source) & replica site for restore purpose.
We have found, only 'Notes' can help us after failover, but Notes are not getting replicated after failover.

Is there any way or any API present which can help us to trigger out resore on the basis of the common attribute of corresponding snapshot on parent & replica site?

Similar to that how we can confirm the completion of specific snapshot copying from parent to replica.

Answer (score 0):

This object mask could help you to retrieve attributes related for snapshots.

**Note**: *A network storage partnership is used to link multiple volumes to each other. These partnerships describe replication hierarchies or link volume snapshots to their associated storage volume.*

```
https://$username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/$networkStorageId/getObject.json?objectMask=mask[parentPartnerships[partnerVolume,type,volume[parentPartnerships[volume,type]]]]
```

For all items in the account:

```
https://$username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage.json?objectMask=mask[parentPartnerships[partnerVolume,type,volume]]
```